# Solving function in difference quotien equation

Tags: functions, fractions

I have the problem Find the difference quotient $\frac{f(2 + h) - f(2)}{h}$ for $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$.

The answer they gave is $\frac{-(4 + h)}{4(2 + h)^2}$

So far I've done:

$$\frac{[1/(2 + h)^2 - 1/4] }{ h}$$

$$\frac{[-4/4(2 + h)^2 - (2 + h)^2/4(2 + h)^2]}{  h} $$

so the $4(2 + h)^2$ is the solution's denominator based on that, which is right,...

So then that leaves $\frac{[-4 - (2 + h)^2]}{ h}$ or $\frac{[-4 - (4 + h^2)]}{ h}$ for finding the top half of the answer. Which is where I'm having a problem.

Comment: A little error, $(2+h)^2$ is equal to $4+4h+h^2$, not $4+h^2$. Now everything should turn out well.

Comment: Oh right, forgot about that. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

for $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$
$$\frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}{h}=\frac{\frac{1}{(2+h)^2}-\frac{1}{4}}{h}=\frac{\frac{4-(2+h)^2}{4(2+h)^2}}{h}$$
$$=\frac{4-(2+h)^2}{4h(2+h)^2}=\frac{4-(4+4h+h^2)}{4h(2+h)^2}$$
$$=\frac{-4h-h^2}{4h(2+h)^2}=\frac{-h(4+h)}{4h(2+h)^2}=\frac{-(4+h)}{4(2+h)^2}$$
Which is the answer as required.